# Webdriver script for clicking on buttons

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using selenium-webdriver, testng, eclipse(galileo). I have got two buttons on the page. I need to write script where: 
1)if first button is clicked it displays different screen 
2)if second button is clicked it displays another page

Can i do it using if-else loop

Code :

```
WebElement browse = driver.findElement(By.id("select"));
browse.click();
if(browse.isEnabled())
{
    System.out.println("If");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Else");
}
```

Here the output in console is : Else

I know i am following wrong way, but please suggest me proper way

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question. Here is my answer.

You should use page Objects for developing script in webdriver.

It is my advice that you google and understand what page object design pattern is?

If your project is complicated you should definitely use it. Because in long run you may find yourself in trouble after the application's UI changes.

Have a closer look at this ---> http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2011/10/10/using-page-objects-with-selenium-and-web-driver-20/

This will answer your question :)

Comment: While I thoroughly recommend using page objects, you DO NOT have to follow the pattern to develop webdriver tests.

Comment: have edited to replace 'must' with 'should'. Downvoting the answer is a bit harsh though. Have tried to show him correct path.

Comment: your code does not make any sense. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I still think "should" is too strong

Comment: I dont care what you think

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend separate tests.

e.g. Test 1: create scenario where button 1 is enabled

Test 2: create scenario where button 2 is enabled

Having "if" in a test is "bad smell"

Comment: Well, if you like it, there is always those arrow buttons to the left!